# What does 'sich gemerkt werden' mean and how is it used?

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage

I was studying for an exam and came across the following sentence, which didn't seem natural to me:

"In den Zellen der Tabelle T **werden sich bestimmte Variablenmengen gemerkt**, die leer sind."

What is the meaning of 'sich gemerkt werden'? Is it a commonly used phrase?

Answer (score 5):

This is a passive that doesn't mention an actor.

"someone" makes a mental note of variables, and that "someone" isn't mentioned. This is used when you want to avoid mentioning the actor of the action (probably "das Programm").

The added twist is that the act of *memorizing* something is actually reflexive (**sich** etwas merken) in German, which makes that construct sound somewhat clumsy, even to native speakers. (I could have bet the example came from an exam, either from a question or an answer, because that would likely be the only place I would have seen such a construct). It's proper German, but not exactly properly styled German. That should also answer your question on common usage.

Comment: I'm not sure it would need to come from an exam; could be documentation.But not good style either way

Comment: This is not an impersonal passive. The impersonal passive lacks a subject, but there there is a subject here: *bestimmte Variablenmengen*.

Answer (score 1):

It's a strange sentence with an unclear meaning. Instead of "wird sich gemerkt" it would be better to say something like "wird gespeichert" or "wird festgehalten". "Sich etwas merken" is reflexive, and in the passive sentence there is nothing to refer to.

Also, what is "Variablenmengen, die leer sind"? Empty sets? Who needs to save empty sets, plural? Hopefully it makes sense from the context.

Answer (score -1):

This is simply a passive sentence using the reflexive verb *sich etwas merken*.

Active:

> Jemand/man merkt sich bestimmte Variablenmengen.

Passive:

> Bestimmte Variablenmengen werden sich gemerkt.

In the sentence given in the question, the subject moved to position #3, so the first position must be filled by an *es*.

What makes the passive sentence quite unusual is the presence of a subject. Generally, a passive sentence with a reflexive verb is only possible with an impersonal (subjectless) passive. Some may even argue it's not a correct German sentence.